# How do I prove the following summation notation problem using weak induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

So I'm trying to figure out a homework problem. We have to prove it using weak induction.

$$\sum_{j=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{j}\ge1+\frac{n}{2}$$

The base case is easy, and I have my induction hypothesis as the sum from $j=1$ to $m$ of $\frac{1}{j}$ is greater than or equal to $1 + \frac{m}{2}$. But I can't figure out how to get to the $n+1$ step. Help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You can find a tutorial on how to format your posts with MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It's standard to do so here, and the basics of MathJax are pretty easy to pick up.

Comment: I think this is easier if you actually expand the terms of this series, and then group them in terms of what you're adding for each increment of $n$: $\left(\frac11\right) + \left(\frac12\right) + \left(\frac13+\frac14\right)+\left(\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\frac18\right)+\cdots$.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the claim holds for some integer $n$. Then note that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{2^{n+1}}\frac{1}{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{j}+\sum_{j=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}}\frac{1}{j}\ge 1+\frac{n}{2}+\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}=1+\frac{n+1}{2}
$$
where we used the induction hypothesis to get the inequality and used
$$
\sum_{j=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}}\frac{1}{j}\geq \frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}
$$
since we are summing $2^n$ terms each of which is at least $1/2^{n+1}$.